# Android: не удаляются файлы на internal storage на некоторых смартфонах

Tags: android

Возникла проблема с невозможностью удалить файл на internal storage на Sony (android 4.3) и Asus (Android 5). На эмуляторах 4.3 и 5.0.1 проблем нет.
На других устройства - тоже. Никаких Exception не бросается, просто метод для удаления не работает.
Удаляю вот так:

```
public boolean deleteFile(Context context, String filename) {
          boolean success = false;
          File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
          if (file.exists()) success = file.delete(); 
          if(context.deleteFile(filename)) success = true; 
          return success;
}
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Какие нужны разрешения для internal storage?

Comment: Для своих файлов никаких разрешений не требуется. А что понимается под _не работает_, как Вы устанавливаете этот факт?

Comment: Файл не удаляется. При этом он был создан, в него можно писать, его можно читать, а удалить нельзя.

Comment: То есть  метод возвращает `false`, а проверка следом за ним `file.exists()` на тот же файл даёт `true`?

Comment: @woesss что возвращают эти методы неизвестно (таких смартфонов у меня нет), но файл остаётся на своем месте.

Comment: Ну а как Вы определили, что файл не удалился, я добьюсь от Вас?

Comment: Прочитав его или вызвав file.exists().

Comment: Файл может не удалиться, если есть открытый дескриптор (то есть файл открыт на запись/чтение). Проверьте код на предмет гарантированного закрытия потоков при записи/чтении, а так же параллельного выполнения оных с попыткой удаления

Comment: @woesss ага! Спасибо, проверю. Это наиболее вероятный вариант.